# Triple integral of a solid bounded by

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

The solid is upper bounded by $z=16-y^2-4x^2$ and lower bounds by $z=7$
What I've done up until now is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_2^{4} \int_7^{16-r^2\sin(\theta)-4r^2\cos(theta)} r\sqrt{(16-r^2\sin(\theta)-4r^2\cos^2(\theta))}dzdrd\theta$$

What I've thought is that maybe the exercise is proposed wrong in the first place due to it makes more sense (and gets easier to solve ) by having the parabolloid equation like this $z=16-4y^2-4x^2$

The answer the sheet has is $(\frac{1664+197 \sqrt(7)}{30}) \pi$
And as you can see, I don't know how to get to that answer.

Comment: Do you want the volume of the solid ? That is not clear in your question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: I see you're not using sin^2(t), that would simplify it a lot

Answer (score 1):

First analyse the bounds of the different variables :
$$z\ge7\iff 16-y^2-4x^2\ge7\iff 4x^2+y^2\le 9$$
So the volume is determine by :
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}-\frac32\le x\le \frac32 \\ -\sqrt{9-4x^2}\le y\le \sqrt{9-4x^2} \\ 7\le z\le 16-y^2-4x^2\end{matrix}\right.$$
Now use Fubini theroem :
$$\iiint_V dxdydz = 
    \int_{-\frac32}^{\frac32} \left(\int_{-\sqrt{9-4x^2}}^{\sqrt{9-4x^2}} 
     \left(\int_7^{16-y^2-4x^2} dz\right)dy\right)dx$$
I leave you the rest of the work :-)

Comment: How one interprets bounds for multiple integration can make or break you

Comment: Your answer gives $\frac{81\pi}{4}$, this isn't the answer OP gives?

Comment: Yes, I know... I tried it, found your answer, so I prefered not to post them, in case I made a few miscalculations :-) But I think my analysis of the domain is right.